# XPages name picker not working with apostrophes

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

Strange issue, I'm using the extlib name picker, looking up a view of names (we don't use a NAB), which can be searched, a name selected and then added. This all works fine. EXCEPT, if a user has an apostrophe in their name. The search works, the name shows, but when you click Add, it simply doesn't do anything, and this is for ANY name with an apostrophe. Has anyone encountered this or know how to get around it? Any help greatly appreciated as there are no errors, or anything written to the console logs or online articles I can find describing it. Thanks Code below:

```
<xp:inputText id="lstPELName" value="#{document1.PELName}"
        maxlength="0" style="display: none;">
        
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="refreshResponse">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
document1.save();
// Set People Leader details
var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent("SetPELDetails");
agent.runWithDocumentContext(currentDocument.getDocument());

}catch(e){
    openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
}}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>

    </xp:inputText>
        

<div class="col-xs-3 no-border" id="divPELPicker">      
    <xe:namePicker id="approversNamePicker" for="lstPELName">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:dominoViewNamePicker databaseName="ppg\dpi.nsf"
                viewName="CurrentProfilesByOwner" labelColumn="SystemName">
            </xe:dominoViewNamePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
        
        <xe:this.pickerText><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Select your People Leader:";
}]]></xe:this.pickerText>
    </xe:namePicker>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-9 no-border" id="divPELName">
<xp:text escape="true" id="cmpPELName"
                        value="#{document1.PELName}">
                    </xp:text>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume somewhere a character conversion is missing, probably to JSON. Can you modify the column in the view, and replace an apostrophe by its Unicode equivalent? That would be \u0027. You might have to escape the \ to make it work, as \\ or even \\\\.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. I expect my syntax was wrong, would you mind supplying an example? I've put in a similar fix in the meantime, using @ReplaceSubstring to replace any apostrophes with * and advised the users to do the same when searching the name picker. Then when I call my LS agent after the name has been picked I use InStr to check if there is a * present and if so swap the * back out for the apostrophe using Join and Split

Comment: Instead of the * you could use the back-quote, and the equivalent of @ReplaceSubstring in LS is Replace(). For the rest: if it works, it works.